# When Transferring files using Multipeer connectivity getting this error some times on iOS 10.0.2 and 10.1

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

When Transferring files using Multipeer connectivity getting this error some times on iOS 10.0.2 and 10.1 getting this error 
[viceroytrace] [ice][error] send binding_request failed(c01a0041)